# Compute F1 estimate variance for a given precision and recall

Tags: precision-recall

For a binary classifier with precision $P = \mathbb P (Y =1 | \hat Y = 1)$ and recall $R = \mathbb P(\hat Y = 1 | Y = 1)$ (where $\hat Y$ is the predicted class and $Y$ is the true class) how can I compute the variance in the estimate of the $F1$ over a sample of size $n$?

It's clear to me that the best way to do this is using monte carlo estimation, but setting up the computation has been tricky. I know how to construct a classifier with a given recall $R$, but then how do I also ensure that it has precision $P$?

Given a sample of size $n$ with $n_p$ examples in the positive class, a classifier with recall $R$ predicts each positive example as positive with probability $R$. For that classifier to also have precision $P$, we should select the false positive rate accordingly, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Your title and first paragraph ask one question (calculating the variance in the estimate for $F1$), and your second and third paragraph ask a different question (ensuring that a classifier with given recall also has given precision). Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you can compute this by directly sampling the predictions and true values for a sample of size $n$ at a desired recall $r$ and precision $p$. Of the values that are truly positive, $r$ will be predicted positive on average, so use $r$ as the parameter for a bernoulli, conditioned on the label being true. Now getting the precision is a bit trickier: note that given a base rate and a fixed recall, the precision is determined by the choice of $\mathbb P(\hat Y = 1 | Y = 0)$. Which can then be used as the threshold for prediction conditioned on the true label being false. Putting it together we have the following code:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
import pandas as pd
import numpy.random as rn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def hmean(a, b):
    return np.nan_to_num(2 / (1/a + 1/b))

p = 0.01
n_iter = 1000
r_steps = 30
p_steps = 40
recall = np.linspace(0, 1, r_steps + 1)[1:]
precision = np.linspace(0, 1, p_steps + 1)[1:]
p_1_0 = recall * p / precision[:, np.newaxis] - recall * p
recall_neg = p_1_0 / (1 - p)
f1s = defaultdict(list)
precisions = defaultdict(list)
sample_sizes = [100, 1000, 10000]
for i in range(n_iter):
    for n in sample_sizes:
        samples = rn.rand(n, p_steps, r_steps)
        pos = (samples < p)
        samples = rn.rand(n, p_steps, r_steps)
        pred_tpos = (samples < recall.reshape(1, 1, -1)) & pos
        samples = rn.rand(n, p_steps, r_steps)
        pred_tneg = (samples < recall_neg[np.newaxis]) & ~pos
        pred = pred_tpos | pred_tneg
        recall_hat = np.nan_to_num(pred_tpos.sum(0) / pos.sum(0))
        precision_hat = np.nan_to_num(pred_tpos.sum(0) / pred.sum(0))
        precisions[n].append(precision_hat)
        f1s[n].append(hmean(recall_hat.reshape(-1), precision_hat.reshape(-1)).reshape(*precision_hat.shape))
```

[image]